# Controlling bash script concurrency, flock inheritance

Tags: bash, shell-script, lock, concurrency

I have a bash deployment script that handles deploying updated code to a Tomcat instance on CentOS, however, both Chef and RunDeck may invoke the script, and since Chef runs periodically there is a chance of a collision.

How do I prevent the deployment script from running twice concurrently?

The standard answer looks to be to wrap the deploy logic in a `flock`.

However, since the deploy restarts tomcat that isn't working -- the new java process inherits the lock and prevents any further deploy scripts from executing.

Is there another way to prevent concurrent execution or a way to prevent `flock` inheritance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can close the file descriptor where `flock` maintains the lock before running the program that you want to run unlocked.

```
(
  flock -n 9 || exit 120
  …
  (exec 9>&-; tomcat &)
) 9>/var/run/my.lock
```